# Posting to wall users use token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have php code that posting in the wall of the user that use in my app. But in the post write

> "post by **_**" (My app name).

**Code**:

```
$fql_info = $facebook->api($fql_query);
if($fql_info[0][offline_access] == 1)
{
   $attachment =  array(
        'message' => "",
        'name' => u("ghfhgfhfgh"),
        'description' => u("fghgfhgfh"),
        'link' => LINK,
        'picture'=> "http://gfhgfhgfhfh"
    );
    $facebook->api('/'.$f[uid].'/feed', 'POST', $attachment);
    $abc.=$f[uid]."\n";
    echo $f[uid]."-".$fql_info[0][offline_access]."\n";
}
```

I want to know how I can to post but without my app name.  User as poster itself, not the application has released it.
is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's not possible. The app name will appear in the post.

Comment: I saw on Facebook someone who could do it, but written as if the user posted his cell phone (nokia).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say but i don't think this is possible . Facebook would not allow us to do that , it will always say Posted via : [Your APP name]